# Sencha Cmd 5 shared package integration workflow

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs5

Can anyone explain how to implement the shared package feature in Sencha Cmd 5 with ExtJs 5? I created a workspace containing two applications. These applications share javascript code, which was placed in the proper packages folder, and the application's respective app.json was modified as instructed [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/cmd/cmd_packages/cmd_packages.html).

The shared code is not being implemented after running the "sencha app refresh" command.  I have been at this for days now.  Below are the steps I took to create the workspace, apps and package:

**Step 1: Create Workspace**

```
sencha generate workspace ./
```

**Step 2: Create Apps**

```
sencha generate app -ext -path ./testapp1/ -name testapp1
sencha generate app -ext -path ./testapp2/ -name testapp2
```

**Step 3: Create Package Called "common"**

```
sencha generate package -name common
```

**Step 4: Drop basic ExtJs class file in packages/common/src folder**

**Step 5: Modify app.json code in both applications to include newly dropped ExtJs class**

**Step 6: Refresh**

```
sencha app refresh
```

After running refresh, I expect to be able to use the code, or at least reference it using FireBug.  Am I missing a step??? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have it correct. the `app.json` file needs to have the `requires` property set to include your `common` package.

```
"requires" : [ "common" ]
```

Then be sure to use `requires` on any class in your application to include the source files from your package.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.foo.Bar', {
    requires : [
        'Common.Util' //or whatever it's called
    ],

    //...
});
```

And finally the `sencha app refresh` so that the bootstrap paths are correctly updated.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now.  1000 Thanks!